# C++ How to correctly round a const float to unsigned int

Tags: c++

So I have a const float that has a range from 0.0 to 1.0. What is the correct way to cast this to an unsigned int either by rounding or truncating?

Would this be acceptable?

```
const float f=0.5f;
unsigned int i=static_cast<unsigned int>(f);
```

Comment: The fact the float is const doesn't matter here.

Comment: @Neil Yeah I didn't think it would matter, but I thought I might as well include that it is; to show that this value will be known, and that problems with overflow or sign won't be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly acceptable if you want to truncate, and if you don't care what happens with negative numbers or overflow.

If you want to round, call `roundf` first (or, if you want a different rounding rule than "half rounds away from zero", write your own code).

If you want to deal with negative numbers or overflow, you need to check before converting.

According to 5.2.9 in the standard, `static_cast` in this case is defined to give you the same value as `unsigned int i(f)`. And I think most style guides would agree that the `static_cast` is preferred (as making casts explicit and noticeable is usually a good thing).

In more detail:

According to 4.9.1:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion trun- cates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

I'm not sure exactly how the const-away works in C++14, but I believe it's not a qualification conversion, but part of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion from 4.1.1:

> A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to a prvalue … If T is a non-class type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of T.

So, `f` has one lvalue-to-rvalue conversion from lvalue `const float` to rvalue `float`, then one floating-integral conversion from `float` to `unsigned int`, so by 4.0.1 it's a standard conversion, so by 5.2.9 it's valid as a `static_cast`.

Comment: Ok thank you, since its a constant that is only supposed to be between 0.0 and 1.0, I shouldn't have to worry about negative numbers or overflow.

Comment: @TriforceOfKirby: In that case, it's always going to convert to 0 unless it's exactly 1.0, of course.

Comment: Yes, I should probably have mentioned that this is being used as a scale value that is multiplied and then stored in a unsigned int.

Answer (score 5):

Just add one half to round:

```
unsigned int i = static_cast<unsigned int>(f + 0.5);
```

Or nothing to truncate - what you have is fine (assuming `f >= 0`)

```
unsigned int i = static_cast<unsigned int>(f);
```

Comment: So that would round it yes, but I don't necessarily care if it's rounded or truncated, I'm just curious if this is considered 'Good Practice' to use a static_cast?

Comment: @TriforceOfKirby static_cast is the prefered cast for this operation.